# How to stop prolog goal executing more than once?

Tags: prolog

I have a fact and a goal like below:

```
disconnected.

join :- disconnected, time(T), send(T).
```

Once this goal executes it should make disconnected false and thus not execute again. I am new to Prolog so I am a bit stuck. I am sure it's something really simple but can't figure it out at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `assert` or `retract` to change the known facts. Or you might use global variables. I am not sure how standard that is.

The easiest would be to declare your `join` with two parameters: input parameter that signifies the current state, and an output parameter signifying the new state.

Comment: thanks, it seems to work with the assert, retract. I just also needed to add dynamic for disconnected. I will try the two parameters join as well.

Comment: imo, using a global variable is pretty much the same as using assert/retract in this case; and it's actually supposed to be faster. on the other hand, it is true that not all prologs support global variables while most have assert/retract.